# SSH tunnelling through a proxy to run BOSH commands on the remote server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, cf-bosh

I'm trying to write a non-interactive script which will create a tunnel to a remote machine through a proxy. I have created a tunnel only to a specific port that is: `25555`.

```
ssh -L localhost:25555:$BOSH_TARGET ubuntu@$PROXY -i id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -f -N
```

I have to use a certificate while targeting the BOSH, which I do.

```
bosh --ca-cert ca-certificate target localhost:25555
```

The credentials are taken in the form of environment variables which I have already set.

The target is set but the BOSH target command tries to connect to UAA server which is on a different port that is: `8443` and the connection times out.

I have tried creating a tunnel to `8443` on my localhost, but the BOSH command tries with `$BOSH_TARGET:8443` instead of `localhost:8443`

All these command take place in a docker container. How do I go about this?

Comment: Did you try to set up a ssh tunnel to `BOSH_TARGET:8443`?

Comment: Yeah i did try, but the BOSH command tries with $BOSH_TARGET:8443 instead of localhost:8443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command gets it working, it seems you have to specifically mention --non-interactive.

```
bosh --non-interactive ${target_opts} target localhost:25555

printf "${BOSH_USER}\n${BOSH_PASSWORD}" | bosh login
```

Since non-interactive doesn't work with UAA